# Как сделать запрос к внешнему API из андроид приложения Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, мобильные-приложения

Пытаюсь написать приложение на андроид для своего сайта. На сайте написал API теперь хочу в приложении получать даныне с этого API.
Много гуглил по итогу в голове каша. Все примеры что находил или не работают или плохо рассказывают.

Помогите написать запрос к API без всяких приамбул. В чистом виде

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен, что вы имеете ввиду "в чистом виде"? При разработке приложений под Андроид часто пользуются сторонними библиотеками. Вы уже выбрали, какую библиотеку вы хотите использовать? Вполне можно обойтись без библиотек, но кода выйдет больше. Ваш вопрос задан слишком обобщенно, уточните хотя бы в вопросе о том, есть ли у вас какие-то предпочтения или ограничения по поводу использования сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве элементарного примера:

Добавляете зависимость:

```
 dependencies {
 implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
}
```

Условно хотим обратиться к API  и получить с эндпоинта "films" данные:

```
String YOUR_URL = "http://www.yourUrl.com/films";

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(YOUR_URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    String result = new String (responseBody);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

}
})
```

Строка result будет содержать результат выполнения запроса в случае успеха.

Comment: Первая же строчка не работает. По идее надо как то так.  `**var YOUR_URL: String = "http://www.yourUrl.com/films";**`

Comment: @AnteFil я вам базовый пример на Java предоставил. Если вы используете Kotlin внесите изменения синтаксиса очевидно же